# Чи існує український текст на зразок "Lorem ipsum"?

Tags: resource-request, типографіка

Порадьте, будь ласка, хорошу цитату тексту з якоїсь української класики, яку можна було б використовувати в якості *«Lorem ipsum»*.

[«Lorem ipsum»](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum) — це класичний беззмістовний текст для тимчасового заповнення текстових блоків при створенні дизайну друкованих видань та програмного забезпечення.

Критерії:

- Бажане використання усіх [унормованих](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F) засобів пунктуації
- Наявність діалогу і прямої мови
- Не надто короткі і не надто довгі абзаци
- Друкований об’єм — до однієї сторінки тексту

Comment: Тут роблять з латинського "Іпсуму" [кириличний](http://generator.lorem-ipsum.info/_russian) (знайшов по посиланню в вікіпедії). А діалогів і прямої мови в іпсумі нема - просто додаєте пунктуацію за власним смаком. Це ж не тільки беззмістовний текст - там шматки слів з латини.

Comment: Десь бачив використання початку з [казки «Хо» Коцюбинського](http://ukrclassic.com.ua/katalog/k/kotsyubinskij-mikhajlo/306-mikhajlo-kotsyubinskij-kho-ranok-u-lisi) в ролі lorem ipsum. Доволі відомий уривок, у школах його взагалі вчать (чи раніше вчили) напам'ять, тож не дивно, що обрали його. Але де я таке бачив — не пам'ятаю.

Comment: Можна ще взяти з перекладів Jabberwocky, там досить незрозуміла перша строфа: "Був смажень, і швимкі яски спіралили в кружві, і марамульки йшли в псашки, як трулі долові". Або "Блищалось, слизі лабузьки на хвиді кружали й спірли, дражнилки всі були дзузьки, і миги застрімли". Колекція перекладів [тут](http://www.wonderland-alice.ru/public/kurij2/JABBERWOCKY_2/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Текст "Lorem ipsum" завоював свою популярність не лише через те, що є достатнім набором слів, а й через те, що є *панграмою*.

**Панграма** - це текст, який вміщає в собі всі літери абетки і тому ідеально підходить для перевірки шрифтів на сторінці.

Для української мови панграм існує чимало. Наприклад:

- *З'їв аґрусу — та ягода цілюща б'є жах інфекцій шипучим «ь»*
- *Протягом цієї п'ятирічки в ґрунт було висаджено гарбуз, шпинат та цілющий фенхель.*
- [Інші панграми на wiki](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0).

Ці панграми можна об'єднувати, доповнювати, аби створити "текст-рибу" бажаного розміру та вигляду. І хочу підкреслити, що такі тексти не зобов'язані містити смислове навантаження. Навіть швидше навпаки: вони повинні бути безглуздими, аби не загострювати увагу дизайнера на собі.

Answer (score 4):

Lorem ipsum – назва класичного тексту-«риби».
«Риба» – слово з жаргону дизайнерів, що позначає умовний, часто безглуздий текст, що вставляється в макет сторінки. Lorem ipsum являє собою спотворений уривок з філософського трактату Цицерона «Про межі добра і зла», написаного в 45 році до нашої ери латинською мовою. Вперше цей текст був застосований для набору шрифтових зразків невідомим друкарем у XVI столітті.

[Переклад українською](http://figli.pp.ua/info/rizne/zhest/dyvna-stattja.html)

> Але щоб ви зрозуміли, звідки виникає це хибне уявлення людей, 
>   цуратись насолоди і вихваляти страждання, я розкрию перед вами всю
>   картину і роз’ясню, що саме говорив цей чоловік, який відкрив істину,
>   якого я б назвав зодчим щасливого життя. Дійсно, ніхто не відкидає, не
>   зневажає, не уникає насолод тільки через те, що це насолоди, але лише
>   через те, що тих, хто не вміє розумно вдаватися насолоді, осягають
>   великі страждання. Так само як немає нікого, хто полюбивши, вважав за
>   краще і зажадав би саме страждання тільки за те, що це страждання, а
>   не тому, що інший раз виникають такі обставини, коли страждання і біль
>   приносять якесь і чималу насолоду. Якщо скористатися найпростішим
>   прикладом, то хто з нас став би займатися якими б то не було тяжкими
>   фізичними вправами, якщо б це не приносило з собою якоїсь користі? І
>   хто міг би по справедливості дорікнути прагнення до насолоди, яке не
>   несло б з собою ніяких неприємностей, або того, хто уникав би такого
>   страждання, яке не приносило б з собою ніякої насолоди?
>
> Але ми цураємось і вважаємо, що  заслуговують справедливого обурення ті, хто, піддався звабі і розбещеним спокусам, які дають їм
>   насолоду, і без тями від пристрасті не передбачили, яких страждань і
>   які нещастя на них чекають. Вони винні так само, як і ті, хто через
>   душевну слабкість, тобто через бажання уникнути страждань і болю
>   відмовляється від виконання свого обов’язку. Втім, тут дуже легко і
>   просто провести відмінності, тому що, коли ми вільні і нам надана
>   повна можливість вибору бажаного, коли ніщо не заважає нам робити те,
>   що нам більше подобається, будь яку насолоду слід визнати бажаним, а
>   будь-яке страждання огидним. Але при деяких обставинах – або на вимогу
>   боргу, або в силу якоїсь необхідності часто доводиться забувати про
>   насолоди і не втікати від тягарів. Тому мудрець дотримується в цьому
>   випадку наступного принципу вибору – або, відмовляючись від
>   задоволення, він отримує якісь інші і навіть великі насолоди, або,
>   зазнаючи страждання, він позбавляється від більш жорстоких.

[Переклад Х.Рекема англійською](https://uk.lipsum.com/), 1914, розділ 1.10.32 & 1.10.33 "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum",

> But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing
>   pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete
>   account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great
>   explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one
>   rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure,
>   but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally
>   encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there
>   anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself,
>   because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in
>   which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a
>   trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical
>   exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any
>   right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that
>   has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces
>   no resultant pleasure?
>
> On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike
>   men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of
>   the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain
>   and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal blame belongs to those
>   who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as
>   saying through shrinking from toil and pain. These cases are perfectly
>   simple and easy to distinguish. In a free hour, when our power of
>   choice is untrammelled and when nothing prevents our being able to do
>   what we like best, every pleasure is to be welcomed and every pain
>   avoided. But in certain circumstances and owing to the claims of duty
>   or the obligations of business it will frequently occur that pleasures
>   have to be repudiated and annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore
>   always holds in these matters to this principle of selection: he
>   rejects pleasures to secure other greater pleasures, or else he
>   endures pains to avoid worse pains.

Comment: Мені здається, що цей допис відповідає на запитання про походження тексту Lorem Ipsum, але зовсім не відповідає типографським вимогам, визначеним у тексті запитання. А саме: (1) із засобів пунктуації, є лише крапки і коми; (2) відсутність прямої мови і діалогів; (3) два дуже великих абзаци тексту.

Comment: Як зрозуміло із пояснення вище, класичний Lorem Ipsum не має прямої мови і діалогів (2),  складається саме з цих двох великих абзаців тексту (3).  Вам потрібне щось своє, до чого навіть назви ще не прозвучало. Ще щойно помітив, що ви хочете "цитату тексту з якоїсь української класики", а Lorem Ipsum -  "умовний, часто безглуздий текст". У вас схоже конфлікт між питанням у subject і поясненням у details.

Comment: Перепрошую, але не можу погодитися. У запитанні йшлося про текст «на зразок» Lorem Ipsum і ніде не йшлося про переклад або еквівалент оригінального тексту (він легко наґуґлюється).